# The field is not enabled even if my radio button is checked

Tags: jquery

I have to elements radio button and text field:

```
<label><input id="GRP010" type="RADIO" value ="900">Radio button</label>
    <input id="AF92" maxlength="254" size="15" name="AF92">
```

I want using jquery to disable text field, but enable it when the radio button is checked and value is equal.

So far I have wrote this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var value2 = $('input:radio[name="GRP010"]').val();
    var checked2 = $('input:radio[name="GRP010"]').is(':checked');

    if (checked2 == true && value2 == '900') {
        $("#AF92").attr("enabled", "enabled");
    } else {
        $("#AF92").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    }
});
```

However, the text field is disable and not enabled if I select the radio button. How to I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: what are the values of value2 and checked2 after you click the radio button.

Comment: What you want is a checkbox, not a radio button. Besides your HTML is a mess. The `input` can't be inside the `label`. The label misses the `for` attribute. The textfield doesn't have a type. None of them have names. So much is wrong here.

Comment: there is no such attribute as **enabled** as you use here `$("#AF92").attr("enabled", "enabled");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no attribute called `enabled` it is only disabled, to use it do this

```
$("#AF92").attr("disabled","disabled"); // will disable
$("#AF92").removeAttr("disabled"); // to enable
```

You also have other problems. First, you are trying to target your input by the wrong attribute `name="GRP010` which does not exist, since you have an id just use that.  Also, you don't have an event handler to change the status of the input once the radio button changes, see the live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyTmm/)

Also, it would be better to start the input as disabled.

Here is the event handler

```
$('#GRP010').on('change', function(){
var checked = this.checked;

    if(checked && value2 == '900')
        $("#AF92").removeAttr("disabled");
    else
        $("#AF92").attr("disabled","disabled");
})
```

Comment: I just changed the condition but it did not enable.

Comment: Try loosing `.attr()` and use `.prop()` [see this on **disabled**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you hsalama so much

Answer (score 1):

To enable it again use this:

```
$("#AF92").removeAttr("disabled")
```

Comment: edit ur question with new code so we can see whats wrong going on.

Comment: Try loosing `.attr()` and use `.prop()` [see this on **disabled**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2)

Answer (score 1):

The function is bind to `ready` so its checking only on startup. You need to bind on click of radio button to check again to enable disable.

inside document ready write.

```
$(".radioclass").click(function(){
    if ($('#GRP010').val()) { //you actually don't need double check
        $("#AF92").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
       $("#AF92").attr("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

`radioclass` give common class to all radio button or use ur preferred selector for those radio buttons.

Comment: Down voter give reason. I still belive it needs to bind to onclick on radio button.

Comment: @deifwud Not valid enough: **1.** You can't 'enable' a disabled item you can only remove the disabled property. **2.** It is perfectly valid to check & manipulate a field on 'ready' or startup. You don't need to bind an event for that.

Comment: @dshai It wont re-check on click of radio button to enable it. This is user requirement.

Comment: typo.. it should be `$(".radioclass")`

Comment: One more thing.. the `radio` button doesn't have a `name` attribute, the selector won't work. Use the `id` instead

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value2 = $("#GRP010").val();
    var checked2 = $("#GRP010").is(':checked');

if (checked2 == true && value2 == '900')
   {
     $("#AF92").attr('readonly', false);
   }
else {
        $("#AF92").attr('readonly', true);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should handle radio button change event

```
$("#GRP010").bind('change', handler);

function handler(){
  var value2 = $('input:radio[name="GRP010"]').val();
        var checked2 = $('input:radio[name="GRP010"]').is(':checked');

 if (checked2 == true && value2 == '900')
       {
         $("#AF92").attr("enabled","enabled");
       }
 else {
            $("#AF92").removeAttr("disabled"); 

        }

}
```

It works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<label><input id="GRP010" type="checkbox" value ="900">CheckBox</label>
<input id="AF92" maxlength="254" size="15" name="AF92">
```

and Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#GRP010').on('change', function(){
        if($('#GRP010').is(':checked') && $('#GRP010').val()== '900')
            $("#AF92").removeAttr("disabled");
        else  
            $("#AF92").attr("disabled","disabled");
    });
});
```

Comment: i use it to check whether the control is going inside or not, forgot to remove here before posting

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're using is looking for a `radio` button with a `name` attribute of `GRP010` - it doesn't have one. Since you have the ID just use that as the selector: `$('#GRP010')`

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.6, you could use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$(function(){
    var radio = $('#GRP010'),
        txtInput = $('#AF92');

    var changeState = function()
    {
        txtInput.prop("disabled", radio.is(':checked') && radio.val() == '900');
    };
    changeState ();

    radio.change(changeState);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TqXE9/